# C++ Truncating Floats in Function Return

Tags: c++, function, floating-point, return, truncate

I have written my own FloatArray class to use for a project.  The problem I'm having is that when I use the get method to return the value at a given index, the returned value is a truncated int and not the entire float.  If I use the overloaded << operator I made within it (it accesses the background array in the normal manner) it prints the entire float just fine.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

My FloatArray Class get function:

```
float FloatArray::get(int index) const
{
    int returnval(0);

    if (index > this->size-1 || index < 0)
        {
            cout << "Index Out of Bounds!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    else
        {
            returnval=this->array[index];
        }

    return returnval;
}
```

Overloaded << operator:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & _ostream, FloatArray &rhs)
{
    for(int i=0; i <= rhs.size-1; i++)
        {
            _ostream << rhs.array[i] << " ";
        }
    return _ostream;
}
```

Example main:

```
int main()
{

    FloatArray floats(2);

    float zero(0.12);
    float one(1.12);
    float two(2.12);

    floats.push(zero);
    floats.push(one);

    floats.expandBy(1);

    floats.push(two);

    cout << "Using overloaded << operator: " << floats << endl;

    cout.precision(2);
    cout << fixed << "Using get function: " << floats.get(0) << " " << floats.get(1) << " " << floats.get(2) << endl;




    return 0;
}
```

Main's output:

```
Using overloaded << operator: 0.12 1.12 2.12 
Using get function: 0.00 1.00 2.00
```

Comment: In `FloatArray::get()` you declared `returnval` as `int`, shouldn't it be `float`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
 v
int returnval(0);
```

Why int?

Comment: DOH! That would be the stupid mistake I made.  I converted this class to a FloatArray from another IntArray class I made and I guess I missed it, even though I read through that block of code at least 5 times.  That's what 24 hours with no sleep does to you.  I sure do feel stupid now!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user2345437, Before you go making all of these `<Type>Array`s, you should look into templates.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an integer variable to hold the return value in the get function. This is automatically converted to a float when you return it, but you can't regain the floating part of the array value.

Either use a float as the type of returnval, or return the value of this->array[index] immediately, without storing it in a temporary variable first. There's no need for an else clause to your if statement as the first part terminates the program.

Answer (score 0):

`float FloatArray::get(int index) const` -- but you return `return returnval;` which is `int` -- so you are lossing precission.